# Mysql найти все записи у которых одинаковая подсеть

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица orders, с колонками `idorder` и `ip`. Нужно написать запрос, чтобы найти все заказы, у которых `ip` адреса из одной подсети.
Например 2 заказа, у которых `ip=100.200.1.1` и `ip=100.200.2.2`, то есть маска `число.число.*.*`

Comment: а маску сети вы тоже сохраняете? если нет, то как определять, входят ли два ip-адреса в **одну** сеть? то, что вы обозвали «маской», не является маской сети. приведённые вами два ip-адреса с равной вероятностью могут и входить и *не* входить в одну сеть.

Comment: маска не хранится. Определить нужно по первым двум числам, если они одинаковы, то входят. маска, скажем так, условная

Comment: @Константин Тогда более правильно вопрос звучит как найти записи входящие в одну подсеть класса "B"

Comment: @Mike да, верно, класс В.

Comment: @Константин И что значит "найти все записи", в каком виде их вывести то, если у нас есть 10 записей из одной подсети, 5 записей из другой подсети и еще 15 записей из совершенно разных сетей. Что на выходе запроса должно быть ?

Comment: @Mike вывести 10 записей + 5 записей, остальные 15 не выводить.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *
  from orders a
 where exists
       (select 1 from orders b
         where b.ip like concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.ip, '.', 2),'.%')
           and b.idorder!=a.idorder)
order by inet_aton(a.ip);
```

Собственно тут показаны обе функции с помощью которых можно находить "одну подсеть". Для сортировки удобно использовать inet_aton например, потому что даст подсети в порядке '98,99,100', а не '100,98,99', если сортировать как текст. Для поиска можно использовать substring_index и like, так по крайней мере есть вероятность что будет работать по индексу (если он есть на колонку ip)

Answer (score 0):

подойдет?

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip, '.', 2) as 'class', COUNT(DISTINCT idorder) as orders 
FROM orders 
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip, '.', 2)
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT idorder)>1
```